# Balloon Inflation

Tags: pressure, everyday-life

I am planning to use an air compressor to inflate a rubber balloon. I need to size the compressor for inflating the balloon, but for sizing the compressor I need the pressure required to inflate the balloon. So, can anyone guide me to calculate the required pressure for inflating a rubber balloon?

Comment: What will you use for your scalar field?   ;-)

Comment: What is the thickness of the rubber balloons wall, what is the initial diameter, what is its modulus of elasticity?

Comment: I think the question should be asked as: How to determine the pressure inside a balloon with radius $r$, and [elastic modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_modulus) $\lambda$? I know a nice-simple answer to this question, which is $P=\frac{2 \gamma}{r}$, where $\gamma$ is the surface tension.

Comment: @twistor59 Bahaha. It's not helped by the fact that I just watched a talk on inflation and did a double take at the question title and "everyday-life" tag. Then I realised this is one of those times where normal people use words differently than I do.

Answer (score 1):

A typical human can exert an over-pressure of ~$9.8kPa$ with their lungs. Given that balloons are designed so that a human can inflate them, I'd say go for a pump that can deliver $10kPa$ of pressure (that's around $1.5psi$ in case you were wondering).